# short story about astronauts/colonists in a hostile planet

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

All die but one, he continues to try to grow plants.... he dies at the end, but is successful growing stuff. I seem to recall the problem might be ammonia in the soil or the air..?

Comment: I remember this one, it's one of the old "classic" science fiction short stories, possibly Asimov. The astronauts had crashed on a planet with an unstable ammonia-based ecology/atmosphere. They knew if they could get earth-like plants to grow it would tip the chemical balance just enough so that the planet would become earth-like. In the end, the final ingredient needed was fertilizer from the main character's body. Now if I can just remember who wrote the story!

Answer (score 10):

I found it! It's Isaac Asimov's [*Founding Father.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Founding_Father_%28short_story%29)

Here's the description from the Wiki page above:

> An exploratory spacecraft of the Galactic Corps, charged with opening
>   up planets for human colonisation, sometimes by terraforming,
>   crash-lands on an alien planet. They find that the ecology is heavy in
>   ammonia, making the atmosphere unbreathable by humans, and the soil
>   unsuitable for the earth-type plants they have brought for
>   colonisation.
>
> As they are unable to take off again, the crew spend their time trying
>   to adjust the environment to make it suitable for possible future
>   human colonists. Although they spend many years at this task, they
>   fail and, one by one, they die of ammonia poisoning.
>
> As the last man dies, the flesh of the buried crew reacts with the
>   soil, providing the catalyst that alters the environment to become
>   more Earth-like.